# How to make my web page geo location enabled?

Tags: seo, local-seo, open-graph-protocol, google-local-search

I am developing a website where businesses will be adding their product and services. I was looking for `META` tags but found out that Google [does not use](https://blog.seoprofiler.com/googles-geo-meta-tags-web-pages/) geolocation Meta Tags. I was wondering whether Google uses OpenGraph tags like given below instead? The point is that if someone uses *Keyword* near *Location Name* or *Near Me*, it shows my page,

```
<meta name="og:latitude" content="37.416343"/>
<meta name="og:longitude" content="-122.153013"/>
<meta name="og:street-address" content="1601 S California Ave"/>
<meta name="og:locality" content="Palo Alto"/>
<meta name="og:region" content="CA"/>
<meta name="og:postal-code" content="94304"/>
<meta name="og:country-name" content="USA"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use Local Business schema, we’re really talking about types and properties within the schema.org vocabulary that are used to categorize and define information about businesses.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business